# Programmatically generated Spree Taxons not showing tree in Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, taxonomy

I am trying to generate a Spree Commerce taxonomy programmatically within a Ruby script (a la seeds.rb).  In the customer-facing product pages the Taxons appear, but they do not work from the Admin pages.

- The "tree" view of the Taxonomy shows the root node, but no children
- On the product edit page, I cannot add any of my Taxons

Here's an example:

```
taxonomy_stones = Spree::Taxonomy.where(:name => 'Gemstone Type').first_or_create
tax_stones = Spree::Taxon.where(name: "Gemstone", parent: nil, taxonomy: taxonomy_stones).first_or_create
tax_diamond = Spree::Taxon.where(name: "Diamond", parent: tax_stones, taxonomy: taxonomy_stones).first_or_create
  tax_fancy_yellow = Spree::Taxon.where(name: "Fancy Yellow Diamond", parent: tax_diamond, taxonomy: taxonomy_stones).first_or_create
  tax_fancy_pink = Spree::Taxon.where(name: "Fancy Pink Diamond", parent: tax_diamond, taxonomy: taxonomy_stones).first_or_create
```

When I run this, entries appear in the database for my Taxonomy and Taxons.  I am able to programmatically associate Products to the Taxons:

```
product_BL212.taxons << tax_diamond
```

I'm guessing that my Taxon-creation code is incomplete or incorrect in some way, but I am not sure how.  Can anyone who is more familiar with Spree's internals provide an example of doing this correctly?

### Further Observations

I used the Admin UI to create sample Taxonomies and have compared the database entries to my generated ones.  The `name` and `permalink` fields in `spree_taxons` are blank for my generated Taxons, but not the Spree-created ones.  When I manually populated some of the values for the root node and two sample children, the taxonomy/taxons still don't work correctly in Admin.

Is it important to have these values populated in `spree_taxons` when `spree_taxons_translations` has the needed information?
If so, how do I get Spree to populate the values for these fields correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Spree::Taxon.rebuild!` after adding the Taxons resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I had the code

```
Spree::Taxonomy.find_or_create_by(name:'Brands')
Spree::Taxon.find_or_initialize_by(name:'brand_name').update(taxonomy: Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name:'Brands'))
```

Running `Spree::Taxon.rebuild!` did not solve the issue. I found out that creating a Taxonomy also creates a Taxon with it and I had to use the ID for the associated taxon in the parent column for the new taxon I was creating.

So

```
Spree::Taxon.find_or_initialize_by(name:'brand_name').update(taxonomy: Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name:'Brands'))
```

had to be changed to

```
Spree::Taxon.find_or_initialize_by(name:'brand_name').update(taxonomy: Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name:'Brands'), parent: Spree::Taxon.find_by(name:'Brands'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Taxon.parent attribute expects a root object.

For example:

`t = Spree::Taxonomy.create(name: "Season")`

`tt = Spree::Taxon.create(name: "Winter", taxonomy: t, parent: t.root)`